# How to finalize work when corutine is canceled?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there a mechanism to finalize something (for example, to close some resources, etc. ) when the coroutine job is being canceled?

Comment: Are you looking for `try { ... } finally { ... }` statement and things like `use { ... }` or there's something else? Can you given an example code? Btw, checkout this part of the doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#closing-resources-with-finally

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example, let's say your [Coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) is scoped with viewModel then when viewModel is cleared you'll get **onCleared callback for [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)** and as your corrotines is scoped with that viewModel so it gets immediately canceled and you'll get a **onCleared callback** and you can close some resources on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of that, but I was hoping that I can somehow handle that from within coroutine..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve similar problem:

```
val job = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
     try {
         //do the job
     } catch (cancelException: CancellationException) {}
     finally {
        //close resources
     }
}
```

When job.cancelAndJoin() is called, cancelException will be thrown and code within catch and finally will be executed.